# JS Function Gives Me Undefined in Console but I'm Expecting a Number

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, undefined

I'm building a JS news ticker that renders strings on a canvas in pixel letters. When the visual length of the rendered string (measured in pixels and represented in the function below by global variable '`calc_w`') exceeds the width (represented by global variable '`w`' in function below) of the canvas, I need to put the second half of the rendered string on the next line. I determine where to break the string up based on the number of spaces in the string (represented below by the variable '`spaces`').

However I cannot figure out why my little function here is returning undefined in the console instead of a number for the `spc_indx[i]` variable.

```
function ins_breaks(str) {
    var spaces = 0;
    var spc_indx = [];
    if (calc_w > w) {
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == " ") {
                spaces++;

                spc_indx[i] = spaces; //Tells the switch where to cut the string.

            }
        }
        switch (spaces) {
            case 4:
                //4 spaces = 5 words.
                var line2 = str.substr(spc_indx[2]);
                //str.replace(' ', '');
                console.log(spc_indx[2])
                break;
            case 5:
                console.log(spc_indx[2])
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Logging '`spaces`' yielded numbers as expected, yet when I assign spaces to a part of the `spc_indx` array, it comes back undefined. Why is `spc_indx` array undefined and not a number like I'm expecting to get back?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9u3ez6gu/22/

Comment: What are `valc_w` and `w` set to, and what is `str`?

Comment: str is the string, it gets passed to the function right at the top.

Comment: I know what that is, I want to know what the value of it is.

Comment: See the attached fiddle. You can make it whatever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spc_indx[i] = spaces;
```

should be

```
spc_indx[spaces] = i;
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! That totally worked! I knew it was something simple that i just wasn't doing correctly. Thanks again. I will select this as the answer as soon as stack lets me.